# jQuery code only works in Console

Tags: jquery, wordpress

In my Wordpress 4.7 i have included some custom js like this:

```
function custom_scripts() {

      wp_register_script ('custom', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/custom.js', array( 'jquery' ),'2.1.4',true);

      wp_enqueue_script('custom');

}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'custom_scripts' );
```

This is my custom.js content:

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function($) {

    // This part works
    $('#menu-main li a').on("click", function(){
        $("body").removeClass("overlay-open");
    });


    // This part does not work
    $('th.bit-date').html('<th class="bit-date">New-Title</th>');
    $('th.bit-venue').html('<th class="bit-venue">New-Title</th>');
    $('th.bit-location').html('<th class="bit-location">New-Title</th>');
    $('th.bit-tickets').html('<th class="bit-tickets" colspan="4">New-Title</th>');

    // This console msg outputs from this script
    console.log("Done!")


});
```

Only the first part of the code is running, while the part that does not work, **do work as expected when it is executed from the console**. This code is going to interact with a plugin generated table. How can I make this js code run after all the plugins are fully executed? (I am open for other solutions as well)

Comment: wp_enqueue_script( string $handle, string $src = '', array $deps = array(), string|bool|null $ver = false, bool $in_footer = false );  set the dependencies array and it will make sure your script loads after.  Same functionality exists in your wp_register_script.  Find out which script builds your table and add it to your dependencies.

Comment: `.ready(function($)` this is the first I see a `document read with function that has a $ in it`. just guessing try to remove it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function($) {

    // This part works
    $('#menu-main li a').on("click", function(){
        $("body").removeClass("overlay-open");
    });


    // This should work now
    $(window).load(function () {
        $('th.bit-date').html('<th class="bit-date">New-Title</th>');
        $('th.bit-venue').html('<th class="bit-venue">New-Title</th>');
        $('th.bit-location').html('<th class="bit-location">New-Title</th>');
        $('th.bit-tickets').html('<th class="bit-tickets" colspan="4">New-Title</th>');
    });
    // This console msg outputs from this script
    console.log("Done!")


});
```